# Ubuntu 12.04 Unusable Wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, audio, ubuntu-12.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. Before, on Natty (11.04), I had ~650kbs. Now I am down to ~30kbs. This makes using my computer almost impossible as I try to set up a new system.

I have removed bcmwl-kernel-source and replaced it with firmware-b43-lpphy-installer to no avail. I also tried the steps [here](http://www.unixmen.com/resolve-slow-connexion-when-using-wifi-in-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal/).

I don't know what outputs/commands would be useful for you to have. I use a 64bit OS on an Inspiron 1545. Sound is also no functional. Please fill me in.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had some driver errors when I installed. I did a fresh install, which brought back sound.

Excessive fan usage was solved by finally installing my graphics card driver.

And finally, it turns out that I was only using wireless to access the repos, which had been heavily bogged down. Great fix for that: Update Manager > Settings > Ubuntu Software [tab] > Download from... [menu] > Other > Select Best Server. If only there were a script to do that...

Okay. All taken care of.